# Class Library Project Cannot Be Found in ASP.NET MVC Solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My solution contains 7 projects, one of which is the web site (ASP.NET MVC). I just added one new Class Library Project 'MyUtility' under my solution, to expose the common functionality globally:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace MyUtility
{
    public class MyHttpProxy
    {
        public static void postToUrl(string url, string post_string)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And in my web site project, I added the reference to MyUtility, but there is a yellow warning icon  over it.

When building the solution, I got error:

> The type or namespace name 'ClubSUtility' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What did I miss? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, the new project MyUtility was using .NET Framework 4.5, whereas the other projects are using 4.0. Changing the setting in the property panel solved the problem.